# Alternatives to wireshark?

Tags: networking, web-server, http, troubleshooting, wireshark

What would be a good option to troubleshoot an interaction of browser with a server besides wireshark?
I mean being able to see what the browser sends and receives.
Is firebug a good alternative or is it only for `css` and the `html` useful?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Unfortunately, we really don't do [product, service and learning material recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa) here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton:This is not learning material request or service request or product.I just ask what other collegues. Not what is the best to buy or compare products etc

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question. Are you looking for techniques to troubleshoot HTTP applications without sniffing the network / recording packets? There are debugging environments built into all modern browsers that may help trace or you could use an intercepting proxy like ZAP.

Comment: @user76678, so what is your question?  It sure looks like this. `What product (piece of software) can I use to capture data`.  The word product is meant to be generic, and include software, (free or non-free), hardware, services, and so on.  Serverfault is about answering technical problems, not being a human powered search engine to help you find software/hardware/etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something HTTP specific, I recommend [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/). It dissects HTTP traffic in very useful ways, does HTTPS decryption, supports Firefox and IE, and can even resend previous HTTP requests or modify them before resending.

Answer (score 1):

Ettercap:  http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/

Kismet: http://sectools.org/tool/kismet/

TCPDump: http://www.tcpdump.org/

To name a few you can try, Ettercap and Kismet are good CLI based sniffers too.